# how can i do to a 2D image and spin it around it's X, Y, or Z axis as if it were a 3D image.in java?

Tags: java, image, 3d, java-2d

I want to achieve the effect of a 2D image I have but a little inclined, for example a plane, I want the image can be rotated about its axis Y. .. anyone can help me with some idea of how to do ..**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need a little linear geometry/algebra, and/or a package to do them for you.

From the geometry point of view, you think of the image as if it's on a plane in space; you're looking at it as if it were back-projected on your monitor.  If the picture is exactly parallel to that screen, and the same size, each point is mapped to a pixel on the screen.  Otherwise you have to go through a computation that makes that mapping, which involves a trig function for the angles in the *x,y,z* directions between that plane and the plane of the screen.  The linear algebra comes in because the easy way to handle this computation is as a series of multiplications of 4×4 matrices.

Now, you could program all that yourself, and for what you're thinking of it wouldn't be all that difficult.  See any good computer graphics text, like [Shirley](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568811241), or [Foley and van Damm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201848406).

As far as a package, there's good 3D graphics in Java.  Even better, there are good tutorials:

- [The Java3D tutorial at Sun](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/).
- the stuff at [j3d.org](http://www.j3d.org/)
- a whole list of them at [java3d.org](http://www.java3d.org/)

Answer (score 0):

In what context ?  Using a 3D API like OpenGL trough JOGL seems to me like the simplest way to achieve this.  Otherwise, if the angle is variable, you'll need some form of software renderer.